# “gcloud app deploy” static website is skiping too many files

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-app-engine

I have a static website and i'm working with GAE when i deploy my website some pictures are not being upload.
How can i fix this problem

Console Message :

```
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones. 
You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[C:\Users\Maher\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2017.06.22\13.28.54.036000.log].
```

this is my app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Folder Tree :

```
>Website
  >www
    >css
    >fonts
    >img
      >photos
        pic_1.jpg
        pic_2.jpg 
        ...
    >js
    blog_post.html
    photos.html
    index.html
  app.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your static files in one dir say assets -> css, fonts, img, js.
Then specify it as a static directory

```
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
  expiration: "1h"
  http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Hello @Supratim,
Thanks for your resoponse but some pictures can't be apload.

Comment: Hi @MaherMahouachi , what do you mean by some picture can't be uploaded?

Comment: I have the same message Some files were skipped. Some pictures and fonts are skipped

Comment: @MaherMahouachi, May be you have lots of files. You can do 1 simple thing. Upload files to google app engine storage(https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) cdn and make them public so that you can access them.

Comment: I think that i don't have a choice i have to upload all pictures in GAE storage thanjs @Supratim